# How do I make the background image continue into the container

Tags: html, css, wordpress

On the following site: http://bit.ly/1gEehw2

I need to get the background for the header to continue into the body and .container div. I tried wrapping container in another div and padding margin/padding and making the background transparent, it did not work. I also tried to use z-index to solve this, and that also didnt work.

Can someone give me some insight on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed some of you code and worked. first give your header a bigger height:

```
.header{
height: 500px;
}
```

clear many many `background:#fff` css from you items like `.jbcbackground` and its children

and add this css to your main body element (give a negative margin-top):

```
.jbcbackground {
margin-top: -250px;
position: relative;
z-index: 100;
}
```